# In Microsoft Teams, can I configure "Activity Feed" to show only threads in which I'm @'ed?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Whether it's the default configuration or me misunderstanding the logic, my Teams' Activity Feed provides no value to me.

I am a member of a large number of teams. I want to configure the Activity Feed to show:

- New messages in which I've been @addressed
- New messages in threads which I've saved
- Nothing else

Can this be done?